# Undefined reference to 'FCGX'

Tags: c, ubuntu, fastcgi

I am trying to compile this program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <alloca.h>
#include <fcgiapp.h>

#define LISTENSOCK_FILENO 0
#define LISTENSOCK_FLAGS 0

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    openlog("testfastcgi", LOG_CONS|LOG_NDELAY, LOG_USER);

    int err = FCGX_Init(); 
    /* call before Accept in multithreaded apps */
    if (err) { 
        syslog (LOG_INFO, "FCGX_Init failed: %d", err);
        return 1; 
        }

    FCGX_Request cgi;
    err = FCGX_InitRequest(&cgi, LISTENSOCK_FILENO, LISTENSOCK_FLAGS);
    if (err) { 
        syslog(LOG_INFO, "FCGX_InitRequest failed: %d", err);
        return 2; 
        }

    while (1) {
    err = FCGX_Accept_r(&cgi);
    if (err) { 
        syslog(LOG_INFO, "FCGX_Accept_r stopped: %d", err);
        break;
        }
    char** envp;
    int size = 200;
    for (envp = cgi.envp; *envp; ++envp)
        size += strlen(*envp) + 11;

    return 0;
    }
```

With this command

```
sudo gcc -I/usr/local/include -lfcgi fastcgi.c -o test.fastcgi
```

I then get this error:

```
/tmp/ccsqpUeQ.o: In function 

fastcgi. :(.text+0x3d ): undefined reference to `FCGX_Init'
fastcgi. :(.text+0x88 ): undefined reference to `FCGX_InitRequest'
fastcgi. :(.text+0xc9 ): undefined reference to `FCGX_Accept_r'
fastcgi. :(.text+0x373 ): undefined reference to `FCGX_PutStr'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think it's because the header files aren't being found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I then get this error:
>
> ```
> /tmp/ccsqpUeQ.o: In function 
> fastcgi. :(.text+0x3d ): undefined reference to `FCGX_Init'
> fastcgi. :(.text+0x88 ): undefined reference to `FCGX_InitRequest'
> fastcgi. :(.text+0xc9 ): undefined reference to `FCGX_Accept_r'
> fastcgi. :(.text+0x373 ): undefined reference to `FCGX_PutStr'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```
>
> I think it's because the header files aren't being found.

No, this is not due to header files not being found. These are linker errors; they happen after your file succesfully was compiled. You're not linking against all necessary libraries.

You'll have to figure out which library contains `FCGX_Init` and add that as `-l<library>` to your GCC call.

Also, order of arguments is important, and your `.c` file *must* come before your `-l` directives, ie.

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include -lfcgi fastcgi.c -o test.fastcgi
```

is wrong, right would be

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include fastcgi.c -lfcgi -o test.fastcgi
```

Also, you should **never** compile code as `root` (do not use `sudo` for building software ever).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I kinda figured it out by just getting rid of the '-I' argument altogether. It compiled with no errors!

Comment: Ah right, this might work because your server run-time loads the symbols from your fcgi library.